# Keepnote on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 20.04

I'm trying to install keepnote on Ubuntu 20.04.
I tried the normal way by running

```
sudo apt-get install keepnote
```

But I got the error

```
E: unable to locate package keepnote
```

I tried installing with a .deb install but then i get error messages saying

```
E: unable to locate package <name of 3 packages keepnote depends on>
```

I tried adding the native Kali Linux dependencies since I know it works on Kali. I also set my server to the best one through the Software & Updates application. I also tried installing the dependencies separately but nothing seems to work.

How can I install keepnote successfully in 20.04?

Comment: From Ubuntu's Package search site (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=keepnote&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), it's only available on 16.04 and 18.04.

Comment: Additionally, it hasn't been updated since 2012 (per their website http://keepnote.org/); surprised it was still available on 18.04.

Answer (score 4):

`KeepNote` does not work on 20.04, without installing obsolete software to make it work. Also, `KeepNote` was last updated in 2012.

Try `CherryTree`. It's a flatpak app, and it's installable from the `Software` store, **and it'll import your old KeepNote database files**.

A hierarchical note taking application, featuring rich text and syntax highlighting, storing data in a single xml or sqlite file. Cherrytree is not just about having a place to write notes and to-do items and keeping them organized, it's also a place you can store links, pictures, tables, even entire documents. It can be your one program for all the miscellaneous information you have and want to keep. All those little bits of information you have scattered around your hard drive can be conveniently placed into a Cherrytree document where you can easily find it.

The Main Features:

```
 • Rich Text supporting Images, Tables, Code Boxes, Hyperlinks and Anchors, Spell Check, Lists
 • Syntax Highlighting supporting many programming languages
 • Password Protection, Powerful Find and Replace utilities, TOC generator
 • Print, Save as PDF, Export to HTML, Export to Plain Text
 • Import from Several other Note Taking Applications
```

CherryTree home page: https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/

KeepNote home page: http://keepnote.org/

Comment: How really does `keepnote` not work? It does not install from repository using APT,  but works while installed using my method [below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1254378/66509). I have tested it - created collection, then folder and note in it.

Comment: @N0rbert The 20.04 upgrade uninstalls Keepnote, probably due to the python2 dependencies that you reference. Rather than installing **obsolete** python2 software from an **archive** repo, or reinstalling **obsolete** KeepNote from 2012, isn't it better to install a currently supported app from the `Software` store?

Comment: I answer to such questions this way keeping in mind that OP may have database in such application. Or habit using it. Also I can't reproduce keepnote package removal on clean fresh VM. Keepnote stays on my system even after `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and/or `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`. So there is something strange on your system. On package level both `python-gtk2` and `python-glade2` are installable on 20.04 LTS because of their absence in the repository and because of satisfaction of their dependencies.

Comment: @N0rbert As I mention in my answer, `CherryTree` will **import** old `KeepNote` databases. `CherryTree` is almost a `KeepNote` clone. I also mentioned that 20.04 **upgrades** remove `KeepNote`... probably because python2 got removed. Although your answer may work, it's really a hack, and not supportable through normal `Software Updates`.

Answer (score 2):

The `keepnote` package [depends on python2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/keepnote), which is now obsolete.

But you still can install it using packages from previous Ubuntu 18.04 LTS release with commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/keepnote/keepnote_0.7.8-1.1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./keepnote_0.7.8-1.1_all.deb
```

and then use it as before.